# Gmap module in Drupal. Change focus of map when on specific page

Tags: google-maps, drupal

Struggling to change the center of a map when on a specific page.
I have a View with markers and I need to use this single view for different pages, but it has a specific marker in the center and when I zoom out I will see other markers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more detailed about what is it that you want to implement? is it that the map should be centered on one specific marker while other markers are still in the div? or you only want to show one marker at a time in center? Also, please provide relevant implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 
Needed to add some code in sites/all/modules/gmap/js/gmap.js

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.vars.markers.length; i++){
    markerCoordinates.push(getCoordinates[i].innerText);
    markerPath.push(getPath[i].innerText);
}
```

here I got the coordinates of all markers and the path of a marker (the page it corresponds to) in an array. Got them from infobox by enabling their show up in admin panel. Later I played with substring to get 2 arrays from coordinates: latitude and longtitude.

After in a loop I compare marker path with current page link (sending it with JSON from index.php) and I get a map cenetered where I needed.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerPath.length; i++){
    if (current_link == markerPath[i]){
        obj.vars.zoom = 17;
        obj.vars.latitude = latitude[i];
        obj.vars.longitude = longtitude[i];
    }
}
```